# In Safari for iPad is it possible to have multiple scrolling areas?

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, scroll

I'm building a web app and I was wondering how it would work in Safari on the ipad, can I have multiple scrolling areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the same way as in the iPhone. I suggest trying it out with the simulator that should come as part of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is the same as with the iPhone as with the iPod touch as with the iPad as with Safari for mac or Pc. The ony difference is on the computer the scroll bars are visible and in the portables versions you have to use a 2 finger swipe to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can look through the source of glovebox, and yes you can have multiple scroll areas, even nesting them. ie an hScoll inside a vScroll, or vv.

The demo is out of date.  I haven't been working on GloveBox as it will soon be built in.
iScroll4 is awesome and well supported! check out cubiq.org

Cheers,
  Jesse

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can use multiple divs with

```
overflow:scroll;
```

as the values of the class/id in your css. They'll scroll really well in Safari, although scroll bounce is a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div scrolling. See [Glovebox](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2010/05/03/glovebox/) for example. Try this [demo](http://risingj.com/GloveBoxDemo/) on the iPad. This enables one finger swipe.